QGIS Zonal Statics doesn't add attributes resulting in KeyError
I have a piece of code that used to work across a lot of QGIS versions and on many systems, but recently has a problem on some systems (in my case only remote servers that I access via remote desktop, with the same QGIS/Python setup version as my local system on which this issue doesn't occur).
This is the code in question (boiled down to essential calls), it appends the needed zonal statistics to the input, this is followed by some other changes on the respective layer and a call on the supposedly appended zonal statistic fields:
    # [A] instantiate vector layer
    vector_layer = QgsVectorLayer(vector_file, "stands", "ogr")
    # ... do some stuff with vector layer ...

    # [B] Zonal Statistics 
    processing.run("qgis:zonalstatistics", 
           {'INPUT_RASTER': raster_file, 'RASTER_BAND': 1, 
            'INPUT_VECTOR': vector_file, 
            'COLUMN_PREFIX': 'xy_', 'STATS': [2]})

    # [C] ... do some more stuff with vector layer ...
    provider = vector_layer.dataProvider()
    provider.addAttributes([QgsField("XY_Round", QVariant.Int)])
    vector_layer.updateFields()
    
    # [D] attempt to use zonalstatistic fields
    for f in stands_layer.getFeatures():
        f["XY_Round"] = round(f["xy_mean"] * 100) if f["xy_mean"] != core.NULL else f["xy_mean"]

On the problematic systems, the last line (section [D]) fails with a Key_Error, indicating that the zonal statistic fields aren't present.
After some research I realized, that on all other systems this runs fine. Apparently the lines in [C] trigger a reload of the vector layer, so that the fields are present.
When doing some further research, I realized that the used algorithm has been marked "deprecated" and has been replaced (in GUI) by "qgis:zonalstatisticsfb" (= feature based), a new version that doesn't allow appending to the input layer, but (for consistency with other tools) forces a new layer (source github issue 40356 on QGIS github).

The old implementation for zonal statistics still is supposed to work, although "hidden" and "deprecated". Apparently something about those remote servers configuration prevents the in-place update from being reloaded in memory as it does on other systems (probably during addAttributes or updateFields).
However recreating the layer after appending the zonalstatistics solved the issue and worked on all systems:
    # [A-B] 
    # ... instantiate vector layer, do some stuff, zonal statistics
    processing.run("qgis:zonalstatistics", 
           {'INPUT_RASTER': raster_file, 'RASTER_BAND': 1, 
            'INPUT_VECTOR': vector_file, 
            'COLUMN_PREFIX': 'xy_', 'STATS': [2]})

    # re-instantiatet vector layer to load zonalstatistic results to memory
    vector_layer = QgsVectorLayer(vector_file, "stands", "ogr")

    # [C-D]
    # ... do some more stuff with vector layer, use zonalstatistic fields

